# Problema generando controladores con scaffolding en .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net

Al intentar generar un controlador para un modelo de mi base de datos Mysql obtengo:
**Error
Error al ejecutar el generador de códigos seleccionado:
"The entity type 'Cajachica' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943."](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.%22)**

Entonces coloque el siguiente codigo:

```
   {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Cajachica>()
           .HasNoKey();
   }
```

En applicationDbContext.cs pero ahora obtengo:

**Error al ejecutar el generador de códigos seleccionado:
"Primary key not found."**

Yo tengo algunas tablas de mi base de datos que no tienen clave primaria, no siempre es requerida. Que puedo hacer?
Edito: Cuando hice el scaffolding de la base de datos se me genero este archivo: gestionContext.cs

Que entre otras cosas tiene:

```
      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasCharSet("utf8")
                .UseCollation("utf8_spanish2_ci");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Cajachica>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasNoKey();

                entity.ToTable("cajachica");

                entity.Property(e => e.Concepto)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("concepto");

                entity.Property(e => e.Idsesion)
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)")
                    .HasColumnName("idsesion");

                entity.Property(e => e.Monto)
                    .HasPrecision(10, 2)
                    .HasColumnName("monto");

                entity.Property(e => e.Tipomovimiento)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("tipomovimiento");
            });
```

Tiene definidas varias entidades que en mi diseño de base de datos no tienen id autoincremental.

Bueno acabo de definir un atributo [Key] Id para una de las clases y funciono

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

#nullable disable

namespace APIGESTION.EF
{

    public partial class Cajachica
    {

        [Key] public int Idcaja { get; set; }
        public int? Idsesion { get; set; }
        public string Tipomovimiento { get; set; }
        public string Concepto { get; set; }
        public decimal? Monto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

No sabia que tiene que haber si o si un atributo id.

Comment: Generaste la base de datos desde el codigo?  Tienes explicitamente marcado con [Key] la clave que usara el objeto?

Comment: Al revés..genere los modelos a partir de la base de datos. Y hay tablas que no llevan clave primaria no me hace falta.

Comment: Es decir que por mas que no tenga una llave primaria tiene que haber un atributo id en el objeto?

Comment: correcto la debes marcar por fuerza para la generacion de scaffolding, es muy extraño que no tengas llaves primarias,

Comment: Son solo algunas tablas pero igual muchas gracias amigo